# RewriteRule rewriting in another directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

my problem is that in root directory I have this rewrite rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule main-page /index.php
```

and it works when I go to the root directory in browser.
But when I visit page.com/panel/main-page it also redirects to the index.php in root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more precise in your matching pattern. Your current matching pattern `main-page` will match any path in this list of examples, which is *not* what you actually want:

- /main-page
- /folder/main-page
- /folder/main-page/whatever
- /some-other-main-page
- /some-other-main-page-in-green

Instead you want to be precise and *only* match the literal string "main-page" as absolute path and nothing else:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?main-page$ /index.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Answer (score 1):

Good question.
That line is correct:

```
RewriteRule main-page /index.php
```

But in that case, we've got if URL contains main-page it always be redirected to the /index.php.

In pure apache2 configuration, below lines always do what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^main-page /index.php
RewriteRule ^(*.)/main-page $1/index.php
```

Comment: Still not working as it should, even on remote host

Comment: Somehow it works when I edited it like that https://pastebin.com/EQ35q5vV

Comment: Oh, no, it's my mistake. If you want to rewrite with a relative path. The rule looks like this:
Two lines instead of the one:
`RewriteRule ^main-page /index.php`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/main-page $1/index.php`